# Click event don't work after append, why?

Tags: jquery, append, alert

I have a probleme with my jQuery code. When I do an append, the event click just work on the first img, not the new (appened).

My code page.htm:

```
<img src="images/del.png" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Delete" class="delegate-del"/>
<img src="images/add.png" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Add" class="delegate-add" />
```

My code jQuery:

```
// When we click on "add.png", the script add the image del.png
$('.delegate-add').click(function(){

        $('#tableautest').append('<img src="images/del.png" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Delete" class="delegate-del" />');

});




 /* The alert just work on the first balise <img src="images/del.png"... 
I don't understand why that's don't work with the new img appended...  An idea ??
*/
    $('.delegate-del').click(function(){
            alert("ok");

    });
```

Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the image is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#tableautest').on('click', '.delegate-del', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
});
```

This will attach your event to any image within the `#tableautest` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/APckr/)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you bind the click event to all existing elements with that class at that point. When you add an element with the same class later, the event has not been binded to that element.

Therefore, you can use the .on() method which will always bind the click event the elements with that class.

```
$(document).on("click", '.delegate-add', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

*.click()* will attach events to elements that already exists. As you are dynamically creating your elements using javascript, it doesn't work.

Use the .on() function instead:

```
$('#tableautest').on('click', '.delegate-del', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('ok'); 
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/